# Add a ViewController to the top of the stack

Tags: ios, swift2, presentviewcontroller

I've been trying to get this working for more than 1 month now and, needless to say, it's getting ridiculous. I can't work out if my method is wrong or if I have a unique setup that is causing issues. I've tried dozens of variations on the following process with zero success.

I have a process in the AppDelegate that calls a function in a delegate controller which gets a user's data in preparation to show their profile.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    notificationsDelegate.userId = thisid
    notificationsDelegate.getUser()
}
```

In notificationsDelegate, the success code for the data retrieval triggers so there is no issue there. The code should then add the user profile view to the top of the stack so it displays when the app reopens but it  never does. The code being used is

```
var root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let pvc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserProfile") as! UserProfile
pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
pvc.user = user
root.visibleViewController!.presentViewController(pvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have an alert within this process so I know it runs but the app just reopens wherever it was when closed without the user controller being added over the top.

Does this process look correct?

BTW, I've tried

```
root.presentViewController....
root.pushViewController....
root.topViewController.presentViewController....
root.topViewController.presentedViewController.presentViewController...
```

The addition of a completion handler on the presenting shows that this is not getting done.

Comment: Perhaps try to add a key value pair to NSUserDefaults and then from viewDidLoad put the correct view on top, whenever the app reopens?

Comment: @lior thanks for the suggestion - i tried methods like that a while back and were also problematic tho may be easier to troubleshoot - main issue is that i have no care nor inclination to know what view is on the top of the stack when the app reopens as it shouldn't matter but maybe i have to unwind the user for no reason just to be sure I'm on a view that can run the presenting code

Comment: now tried root.pushViewController... and no good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally worked this out.....

There seemed to be some issue with the root controller - I'm not sure what - but this seemed to just refuse the presentation of the new view without crashing the app.

So first I needed to find the actual top controller whilst still in AppDelegate and pass this to notificationsDelegate.

I added the following to notificationsDelegate.

```
var topview: AnyObject?
```

I added the following to the didReceiveRemoteNotification.

```
notificationsDelegate.topview = self.topViewController()
```

And then find the top controller using the following.

```
func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow != nil {
        return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!)
    }
    return nil
}

func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    if rootViewController == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if rootViewController!.isKindOfClass(UITabBarController) {
        let tabBarController: UITabBarController = (rootViewController as? UITabBarController)!
        return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
    }
    else {
        if rootViewController!.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) {
            let navigationController: UINavigationController = (rootViewController as? UINavigationController)!
            return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        else {
            if (rootViewController!.presentedViewController != nil) {
                let presentedViewController: UIViewController = rootViewController!.presentedViewController!
                return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController)
            }
            else {
                return rootViewController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this..?

```
let root = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let pvc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UserProfile") as! UserProfile
pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen
root.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(pvc, animated: true , completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thx Vatsal - unfortunately this also does not appear to work either - I'm wondering if the view is being placed under some other view but can't find a way to bring it to the front

Comment: A completion handler shows that it is not being placed elsewhere but is definitely not even getting presented